# Swift - Check nil of an unwrapped optional variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7.3, swift3

I am having a model class as follows, which is in a library written in Objective-C. I am consuming this class in my swift project. In swift it becomes property of type `String!`. Sometimes that property will be nil. So, I am testing the nil validation as follows:

Vendor.h

```
@interface Vendor: NSObject {

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *middleName;
}
```

In my Swift project, I am checking the nil validation for the middleName property as below:

```
if anObject.middleNam != nil { // Here, It throws runtime error: fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

It throws me an following runtime error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If the objective-C properties exposed in swift as `String?` then I would have used the following:

```
if let middleName = anObject.middleName {

}
```

How would I check for the unwrapped optional variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `if let` with implicitly unwrapped optionals – although the `!= nil` check should work properly with `middleName`, how is `anObject` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want ObjectiveC property to be exposed in Swift as optional, mark it with **_Nullable** tag like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * _Nullable middleName;
```

Now middleName name would be optional of type `String?` instead of `String!` and you could conditionally unwrap it.

Read more about [Nullability in ObjC](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

Comment: Note that OP's property is already exposed in Swift as an optional (it's just implicitly unwrappable) & he can use conditional unwrapping on it. In Swift 3, an implicitly unwrapped optional is the exact same type as a regular optional – it just has an attribute telling the compiler that it has the option to force unwrap it in certain situations. And these situations don't include `nil` checks or conditional unwrapping. OP's code is working fine for me – I suspect his problem is that `anObject` is defined as an IUO and that's what is getting force unwrapped.

Comment: Although I definitely agree that adding nullability tags to obj-c types is a good way to go, especially when interfacing with Swift.

Comment: @originaluser2 I agree to your point. it will be implicitly unwrapped optional, and he can still use conditional unwrapping on it but compiler wont complain if you are not doing and this would cause crash in situations like ``let middleName:String = object.middleName` . So its a good practise to mark with nullable tag, thus who ever is going to use it will get compiler warning and he can handle it safely.

Answer (score 3):

As Anil mentioned, the best solution would be to edit your objective-c code to add some `_Nullable`. But, as I understand, your Objective-C code is a library that you cannot edit. So, you have to deal with these `String!` that can be `nil`.

But you can simply use `if let` technique like this:

```
if let firstName = vendor.firstName {
    print("Here is my firstName: \(firstName)")
} else {
    print("I have no firstName")
}
if let middleName = vendor.middleName {
    print("Here is my middleName: \(middleName)")
} else {
    print("I have no middleName")
}

if let lastName = vendor.lastName {
    print("Here is my name: \(lastName)")
} else {
    print("I have no lastName")
}
```

With this `Vendor` code, it returns the following result:

```
@interface Vendor: NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *middleName;
@end
@implementation Vendor
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.firstName = @"Julien";
        self.middleName = nil;
        self.lastName = @"Quere";
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

Result:

```
Here is my firstName: Julien 
I have no middleName 
Here is my name: Quere
```